# Searching by artist name for imported music

Tags: itunes, music

I imported a CD to my iTunes library on my computer.  It automatically detected the name of the artist and name of the CD.  Then I synced my iPhone to my computer and when I search the artist's name for the CD it does not show up. However, when I search the songs they do show up.

How do I get the album to appear when I search the artist name?